# Ignore CSV File header from uploaded CSV file

Tags: csv, oracle-apex

I am using APEX DATA PARSER for parsing the data from CSV file, while parsing the file the table header also saving to the database. how to remove that?

Source Code:

```
IF p_table_name = 'Staging_table' THEN 
     l_columns_item :=  'col001,col002,col003,col004,col005,col006'||',col007,col008,col009';
END IF;

l_ddl :=
                'insert into '
                || p_table_name
                || ' '
                || 'select '
                || l_columns_item
                || ' '
                || 'from apex_application_temp_files f, '
                || '           table( apex_data_parser.parse(
                                                            p_content => f.blob_content,
                                                            p_file_name => f.filename ) ) p '
                || 'where f.name ='''
                || p_file_name
                || '''';
```

The CSV File headers and values are saving to the DB:(Both Header and Values):

CSV Header:

```
Name  - DSR - ID  -  External_Id -  Customer -   Created - Date/Time - Request Type -   Created By
```

CSV Values:

```
ER_120 -1715 - 120 - 1815093826 - TEST CUSTOMER - 8/4/2020 13:35    - TEST  QUEUE -     XXX
```

So i want to save only the values. how to remove the csv file header using APEX DATA PARSER?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.1/aeapi/PARSE-Function.html#GUID-B815CF74-C469-4F78-9433-643D1339E930) there is a skip argument, so:

```
apex_data_parser.parse(
                      p_content => f.blob_content,
                      p_file_name => f.filename,
                      p_skip_rows => 1
)
```

Comment: Hi Alex Poole,

It's working fine, thanks a lot for your quick response.

Regards,
Yokes

Comment: Hi Alex,

I want to get first header row, when i uploading the CSV files, is there anyway to get that logic?

Comment: @YokeswaranGandhimohan - looks at the docs I linked to; `p_max_rows => 1` instead of `p_skip_rows` ?

Comment: Hi Alex,

While  i am using the p_max_rows => 1 then it will showing no data found error, i have only one record in my csv file, meantime i want to fetch the file headers rows and columns values when i uploaded the csv file before parsing the file using apex_data_parser, is there any idea i will use some hidden item to manage those values please help me

Comment: If you only have one row in the file is that a header or data row? I'm not really following I'm afraid. I think you should ask a new question and include a sample CSV and the result(s) you are trying to get.

Comment: Hi Alex,
You are correct there is One Header and One Data Row, but i want to get the file header and columns before parsing when i uploading the file.